# Run dense_rank() window function in update query - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.*, 
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY u_a_id, column_name ORDER BY line_num, e_id) AS new_seq_id
FROM tab t;
```

I have a column `my_seq` with `new_seq_id` and I need to update it. Is there a way in Oracle to use the above in update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`:

```
merge into t using
      (select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by s.u_a_id, column_name order by line_num, e_id) as new_seq_id
       from t
      ) s
      on s.u_a_id = t.u_a_id and s.column_name = st.column_name
when matched then update
    set t.my_seq = s.new_my_seq;
```

Comment: It gives me - SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Comment: @dang . . . I changed the answer so it should work.